# Map automation to iterate through attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages

I have a python code which iterates through all attribute fields and creates a map for each field automatically. However, in the code I have to specify each attribute manually which was fine so far. Now I have an attribute table with many fields and I need a way to do the same without specifying the attributes manually (as done with "Attrlist" in the code. Any suggestions?

This is the code I am using so far:

```
outPath = "D:\\Atlas\\test\MxdMaps\\Mxd_MapAutomation\\"   
# list of attributes with the same datatype
attrlist = ["EthnicGroups_totnumberoffarmhh_txt_WNHDeAA01", 
            "EthnicGroups_totnumberoffarmhh_txt_WNHDeAA02",    
            "EthnicGroups_totnumberoffarmhh_txt_WNHDeAA03"]
# layer which has to change the attribute field
featurelayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "EthnicGroups_totnroffarmhh")[0]
# text element that has to change (e.g. title...)
title = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "map_title")[0]
for attr in attrlist:
        #if featurelayer.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
                #print attr
                # change value field
                featurelayer.symbology.valueField = attr
                #featurelayer.symbology.addAllValues()
                featurelayer.symbology.reclassify()
                #print "Break values: %s" % featurelayer.symbology.classBreakValues
                # change tilte
                title.text = attr
                # update view
                arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
                arcpy.RefreshTOC()
                # export as jpeg
                outJPEG = os.path.join(outPath, attr + ".jpg")
                arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, outJPEG, "PAGE_LAYOUT", 200, 200, 300, False, "24-BIT_TRUE_COLOR", 90, False)
                # export as AdobeIllustrator .ai
                #outAI = os.path.join(outPath, attr +  ".ai")
                #arcpy.mapping.ExportToAI(mxd, outAI, "PAGE_LAYOUT", 200, 200, 300, "BEST", "RGB", "VECTORIZE_BITMAP", False)
del mxd
```

Comment: arcpy.ListFields(featurelayer,"*","String") http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000012000000 will give you all the string fields in a feature class - is that what you're after?

Comment: I think you should accept the answer to your first question and then edit out your second question because it should be researched/asked separately.  The desirability of one question per question is mentioned in the [Tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[arcpy.ListFields()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000012000000) will give you a list of objects. You just need to get the names from those objects.

```
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(lyr)]
```

Another round about way of getting them would be via a [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) but that also includes the shape field.

```
field_names = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,"*") as cursor:
    field_names = cursor.fields
```

Comment: Thanks! I am almost there! Can you also tell me how I would change the code if I wanted to leave out like the first 20 fields and the last 2 fields from the List?

Comment: field_names[20:len(field_names)-2]